# Chart barh matplotlib - overlap bars

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new user of matplotlib and I have a problem with chart barh: overlap bars.
When  plot the graph, the bars draws overlapped and I haven't found the reason. In my opinion the problem is on re-size the graph. I re-size it, because in the future I will insert title, legend and x,y description. I try some solution, but I have one solution!!
This is my code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
    from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
    from matplotlib.artist import Artist
    import numpy as np
    from decimal import *
    import datetime
    #Size
    width = 360
    height = 240
    dpi = 80.0
    colors = ['#be1e2d',
            '#666699',
            '#92d5ea',
            '#ee8310',
            '#8d10ee',
            '#5a3b16',
            '#26a4ed',
            '#f45a90',
            '#e9e744']
    #Data
    columns = ['2005','2006']
    data = [[2.6,3.5],[2, 1.5]]
    linewidth = 1
    N = len(columns)
    
    ind = np.arange(N)  
    #Re-Size
    rdata = len(data) if columns is None else len(columns)
    heightColumn = height*1.0 / (rdata) / (len(columns))
    heightColumn = heightColumn/dpi
    fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(width/dpi,height/dpi),facecolor='w')
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5])
    #Draw
    tupleRects = ()
    idxColor = 0 
    valPositionCol = ind
    for dat in data:
        rects = plt.barh(valPositionCol, dat, heightColumn, color=colors[idxColor], alpha=0.8,  
                         linewidth=linewidth)
        valPositionCol=valPositionCol+heightColumn
        idxColor += 1
        if idxColor==9:
            idxColor = 0
        tupleRects += (rects,)
    plt.show()
```

THANKS

---

The code is the same, but I change the data (`columns[]` e `data[]`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm


from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
import numpy as np
from decimal import *
import datetime
#Size
width = 360
height = 240
dpi = 80.0
colors = ['#be1e2d',
            '#666699',
            '#92d5ea',
            '#ee8310',
            '#8d10ee',
            '#5a3b16',
            '#26a4ed',
            '#f45a90',
            '#e9e744']
#Data
columns = ['2005','2006']
data = [[1.5, 1.5], [1.5,1.5], [1.5,1.5]]
linewidth = 1
N = len(columns)


ind = np.arange(N)  
#Re-Size
height_of_group = .9
   

heightColumn = height_of_group / (len(columns))
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(width/dpi,height/dpi),facecolor='w')
ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.5])
#Draw


tupleRects = ()
idxColor = 0 
valPositionCol = ind
for dat in data:
    rects = plt.barh(valPositionCol, dat, heightColumn, color=colors[idxColor], alpha=0.8,  
                     linewidth=linewidth)
    valPositionCol=valPositionCol+heightColumn
    idxColor += 1
    if idxColor==9:
        idxColor = 0
    tupleRects += (rects,)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I have variable data and I have to find a stable algorithm.

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mis-understanding the meaning of height ([doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.barh)). The units are in axis units, not pixels.

```
heightColumn = height*1.0 / (rdata) / (len(columns))
heightColumn = heightColumn/dpi
```

to

```
height_of_group = .9
heightColumn = height_of_group / (len(data))
#heightColumn = heightColumn/dpi
```

will get non-overlapping bars with just a bit of extra space between the groups.  You can adjust the space between the groups by making `height_of_group` larger or smaller so long as it is less than `1`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. A question: since I'm new user of matplotlib, what it means the value 0.9??

Comment: Another question, is this operation valid for much data, too?

Comment: The units of `height` are in the axes units.  The bars in given `dat` are separated by `1` in these units (given the way you are plotting them against `ind`).  Thus, if you want a gap between the groups, the sum of the height of all the bars (in a group) needs to be less than `1`.  `height_of_group` sets what the sum will be, so in this case the bars in the `N`th group will go from N to N+.9 in axes units.  This should work for any number of columns and length of data.

Comment: Thanks a lot a lot !!! Another question: if I have a bar graph, what is the difference (about 0.9 value)??

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Comment: Sorry, with bar graph (in my example: rects = plt.bar(...) ), is the value 0.9  still valid for the units of width??

Comment: yes.  `bar` and `barh` seem to be nearly identical except for flipping an axes.  If this solved your problem, can you accept my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I have bars overlapped with following data:              columns = ['2005','2006'] and data = [[1.5, 1.5], [1.5,1.5], [1.5,1.5]]. why???

Comment: @user1410756 Posting comments as answers is discouraged, it would have been better to edit your question.  See the edit to my post, you need to scale the size of the bars based on the length of `data` not `columns`.