# Move matplotlib bar plot error bars to the center

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have two pandas dataframes, one with data and one with errors, and I can make a barplot with these using

```
ax = df.plot(kind='bar',yerr=errordf)
```

And this works fine for most of what I want, except that the error bars are plotted at the caps of each bar (the usual). What I need to do is move the error bars to a y value of 1.0, so that rather than checking if a bar plus its error encompasses the true value of 1.0, I can just check whether a bar enters the error bar extending from 1.0. How can I change the y-position of an error bar?

Comment: You need a new errorbar (`plt.errorbar`) with all `1`s for the y coordinate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place Matplotlib errorbars NOT in center of bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933259/place-matplotlib-errorbars-not-in-center-of-bar)